# NativeScript RequestPermission

Tags: android, permissions, nativescript

How i can do for use android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions or android.app.Activity.requestPermissions ? 
Because it's always undefined

I want to do this

```
var context = android.content.Context;
var wifi_service = application.android.context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);

wifi_service.setWifiEnabled(true);  
var rs = wifi_service.startScan();

console.log(android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions); // undefined
console.log(android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.requestPermissions); // undefined

application.android.registerBroadcastReceiver(
  android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION,
  function onReceiveCallback(context, intent) {      
     var tp = wifi_service.getScanResults();
     console.log(tp); // empty []
     console.log(tp.size()); // 0
  });
```

but array tp is always empty and i thing that because i need the right permission, and on android 6 we need to ask it

i also add on manifestfile :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

also add on C:...\app\App_Resources\Android\app.gradle :

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
    , compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+"
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove and add the android platform? Here is an example:

```
tns platform remove android
tns platform add android
```

Answer (score 0):

For fixe the issue, we need to upgrade CLI and recreate application.

I created a new application and i start it from the beginning and that work ! :) 
I think that upgrade of CLI solved the issue, and we need to re-create an app because the \node_modules\tns-core-modules it's not the same

Here the code to fix the scan result issue :

```
    var context = android.content.Context;
    var wifi_service = application.android.context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifi_service.setWifiEnabled(true);  

    var rs = wifi_service.startScan();

    var hasPermission = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23;
    if (!hasPermission) {
        hasPermission = android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ==
        android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(application.android.foregroundActivity, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    }

    var ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 555;

    if (!hasPermission) {
        android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        application.android.foregroundActivity,
                        [android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION],
                        ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    application.android.registerBroadcastReceiver(
            android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION
            , function onReceiveCallback(context, intent) {    
                var tp = wifi_service.getScanResults();
                console.log(tp);
            });
```